# Show an array(string) of images path in a picturebox, Mistake

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have this code to show 4 images in a picturebox, but it doesn't work, only shows the last image

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(array[i]);
            pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(array[i]);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Timer`, such as `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` (if this is for `WinForms`), to execute your code. Set the `Interval` to 2000 ms, and change `pictureBox.Image` in there.

The way you've got it now, you're locking the UI thread for 2 seconds and then changing the image again. The user won't see anything except an apparently frozen app for 8 seconds, and then they'll see the last image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your interface before the sleep or main thread will be blocked and interface will not be updated:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(array[i]);
        pictureBox.Image = Image.FromFile(array[i]);
        pictureBox.Refresh();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }
```

Also, doing an sleep on main thread is NEVER a good idea, a better approach is to have a timer and change those images at regular intervals.